# Апдейт функционала сайта у части пользователей

Tags: php

Приветствую. Есть сайт на php. Допустим, у него очень много пользователей, и разработчикам сайта нужно выкатить новый функционал только для части его пользователей, чтобы протестировать и собрать фидбек, исправить ошибки и тд.

В реализации я вижу это так: допустим на сайте 100 000 пользователей и я хочу выкатить апдейт только для первых 10 000, т.е. алгоритм следующий: брать id пользователя, если id >= 1 и id <= 10 000, то включать ему функционал, если нет, то пользователь соответственно его не видит. Я считаю, велосипедом обварачивать код нового функционала в условные блоки?

Как думаете Вы?

Comment: А потом после тестирования забудете удалить какое-нибудь одно из таких условий и всё будет очень плохо :) Такие вещи обычно делают более хитро и не всегда на уровне исходников сайта (в nginx, например, тоже есть инструменты для A/B тестирования), но тут уже я сам довольно плохо информирован

Comment: @andreymal вот об этом я тоже думал :)

Comment: Почитайте про А-В тестирование. По хорошему, у вас не должно быть "пользователей php скрипта", а должна быть одна, максимально простая, точка входа, которая уже решает, что и кому показывать. В частности для выборочного тестирования вводите генератор случайных чисел, например от 1 до 10, и отдавать новую версию тем, кому выпало 3.

Answer (score 1):

Если все пользватели на сайте авторизируются - можно и так сделать, однако может быть что ежедневные пользователи которые авторизуются имеют ID больше 10,000 т.е они не увидят функционал а пользователи которые попадают в от 1 до 10.000 например редко заходят... думаю такая проверка не эффективная будет.
Можно создать отдельну таблицу в базе, и каждый кто авторизируется (не важно с каким ID) его ID записывается в таблицу Feedback... т.е делаем запрос к базе, нет ли такого ID.. если нет и не превышен лимит участников (10000) то записываем данный ID в базу, если уже имеется ID или лимит превышен- просто выходим из запроса...